# Where does the name Eve come from?

Tags: names, eve-chava

The English version of the name Chava, the first woman, is Eve. What is the meaning and etymology of Eve?

I heard in a class once that the name Eve is connected with the word "evil" because that is how the non-news used to look at women, and therefore the English version should not be used. What is the source for this?

Comment: Eve /iːv/ is an English given name for a female, derived from the Latin name Eva, in turn originating with the Hebrew חַוָּה (Chavah/Havah – chavah, to breathe, and chayah, to live, or to give life). The traditional meaning of Eve is life or "living". It can also mean full of life and mother of life. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eve_(name)

Comment: Probably a myth on the "evil" part. Western non-Jews typically have difficulty pronouncing the guttural "chet" sound.

Comment: @Harel13 Your answer that you source to says "Eue or Euan in Greek could either be a simple mis-transliteration, or perhaps..." It doesn't seem like it is so clear why they used that version instead of Hava.

Comment: Likely the reason is that the Vulgate was authored by Jerome, one of only two Church Fathers who actually knew Hebrew. Because of this, he was able to provide a more proper transliteration of the name. Most other Christians probably had more difficulty pronouncing both Chava and Hava, and so the name eventually became Eve.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the focus of your question. Are you looking for the etymology of an English word/name -- in which case this is not in scope. Or are you looking for a reason that the English word Eve was chosen to represent the Hebrew Chava.